# Return the same type that one of the parameters has in Java

Tags: java, generics

I was wondering if there is a way to return from a method either a `Dog` object or a `List<Dog>` for example, using Java generics or any other tool in Java.

I tried the following, but I highly doubt it's correct or safe;

```
<T extends Dog> T method(T param){
     // do stuff
     return (T) result; 
}
```

If the param is `Dog` I want to return `Dog` and if the param is `List<Dog>` I want to return `List<Dog>`

To sum up, I want a method which returns the same type that one of the parameters has.

What changes would I need to apply to the above method, in order for it to work and be as safe as possible to use?

Comment: Why not just return `List<Dog>` proper, and then handle the case of the list having only one element in it?

Comment: Why do you need to do it? I would just return a `List` with a single element. Or have a method to get a list and one *with a different name* to return a single instance.

Comment: If the param is `Dog` I want to return `Dog` and if the param is `List<Dog>` I want to return `List<Dog>`

Comment: you want to use different parameters and different return types -> then you should create two methods.or pass in an array <T extends Dog>... params and return an array <T extends Dog>[]. this way you can put in 1..* elements and always process it the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more non-restrictive method can be;

```
<T> T method(T param) {
     T result;
     // whatever
     return result;
}
```

Ofcourse, this method does not allow any restriction, in which case, you will require to create two different methods.

Comment: That was actually what I was looking for..but I was confused, pretty simple turns to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two functions with the same name, accepting different parameters:

```
<T extends Dog> T method(T param){
 T result;
 // do stuff
 return result; 
}

<T extends Dog> List<T> method(Collection<T> param){
 Collection<T> result;
 // do stuff e.g. result = param.stream().map(this::method).collect(Collectors.toList()))
 return result; 
}
```

Of course these are *different* methods, any generic code can be extracted into another private method.